# [Unity]Gfx.WaitfForPresent only noticeable on Android (lowers fps)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm making an app for Google Cardboard. I downloaded the SDK and started working on the project. There is a problem though. I have an (almost) empty scene with the SDK prefab, a directional light, and a canvas (FPS counter). When running in editor, nothing seems off. There is steady fps and no weird peaks in the profiler. But when I connect (adb) my android device and run the profiler. I have a constant super high usage in Gfx.WaitfForPresent. The fps drops to about 40 (instead of the desired 60).

I have checked on Vsync, but it was already turned off. I tried every frame, and every second frame. No result. So I tried 'Application.targetFrameRate = x'. Tried it with multiple framerates, but I couldn't even lower the framerate. What is wrong here. It's an empty scene, it should run at more than 60 fps right?

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the issue was. Somehow the Carboard.cs script from google caused this issue. I'm running at steady 60 fps now. Will elaborate if I find more specific info.

Comment: Any chance you remember what the flaw was?

Comment: I am not really sure, but I remember updating to the latest google carboard sdk for Unity. There were also loads of poly's in the scene. Occlusion culling is also a way to improve FPS on android.

Comment: Found my problem was an OS bug. Sorted. Thanks for replying.